# Is it correct to use the present perfect after a second conditional?

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Given the following scenario:

I had some books; I read them all; I gave them away.

Would it be correct to follow this up - in reference to the present - with the present perfect?

> ...but even if I still had those books today, I probably wouldn't **have read**
> them again.

It seems to me that the correct tense in this context would be the plain present:

> ...but even if I still had them, I probably wouldn't **read** them again.

Comment: They're both grammatical, and while some folks might perceive a meaning difference, others wouldn't.

Comment: English does not have a "second" conditional. This is just a dangerous bit of ESL teaching that deceives a lot of you.

Comment: "would have read" is not present perfect. It's "would have" + past participle. The "have" isn't present tense, it's infinitive

Answer (score 2):

They're both correct, but they mean different things.

> I probably wouldn't have read them again.

means you wouldn't have read them between the time you gave them away and now.

> I probably wouldn't read them again.

means you wouldn't have read them again ever -- before now or after.

Comment: Sorry, the first option just doesn’t sound correct after “if I still had them“ which I interpret as “if I had them right now and had never given them away.“

Comment: I don't see the problem. That counterfactual negates having given them away in both options.

Comment: Yes, but there's a difference between "if I had kept them, I probably wouldn't have read them again anyway" and "if I still had them now, I probably wouldn't read them again anyway." The pivotal factor for me is the present. I would never say "I have no appetite today; if you put a pizza in front of me, I *wouldn't have eaten it." the only thing that seems correct is, "I wouldn't eat it."

Comment: The difference is that appetite is known to be transient. Possession of tangible is continuous -- if you had them before, and you still have them now, you didn't give them away. The qualifier "still" reinforces this.

Comment: Also "put a pizza in front of me" is a present tense action, so it makes no sense to refer to anything in the past. "I've had no appetite all week. If you had put a pizza in front of me, I wouldn't have eaten it."

Comment: And "still...today" reinforces the present in my example. There's no mention of the past, so I can't see how WOULDN'T HAVE READ makes any sense.

Comment: This isn't a grammatical issue. "still have them today" implies "hadn't given them away", so you can use them almost interchangeably.

Comment: Unless you're a stickler (Even if I had still had those books, I wouldn't have read them), a mixed conditional is fine.